# Writing query to fetch records from two file in Spark based on timestamps criteria

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

FileA has data like this with start and end time stamps as the last two columns

```
dataa, data1, 9:10, 9:15
datab, data2, 10:00, 10:10
datac, data3, 11:20, 11:30
datad, data4, 12:30, 12:40
```

FileB has data like this with start and end time stamps as the last two columns

```
dataaa, data11, 9:13, 9:17
databb, data22, 10:02, 10:08
datacc, data33, 6:20, 6:30
datadd, data44, 12:31, 12:35
```

Perform a join between this two file, which should result the following from FileB,

```
databb, data22, 10:02, 10:08
datadd, data44, 12:31, 12:35
```

The criteria for join is the start time of FileB should be greater than start time of FileA whereas end time of FileB should be less than start time of FileA.

how to to write the code it in spark-sql.?

Comment: what have you tried so far? and what is the programming language used?

Comment: cartesian join is what i have tried with, but it becomes bottleneck on the huge datasets. so I am thinking towards udf. do you have any other idea .??

Comment: which language : scala or python or R?

Comment: spark-sql.. or python..anyone would be fine..

Answer (score 0):

You can create common `schema` for both files as the structures of both files are same.

```
val schema = StructType(Array("col1", "col2", "start", "end").map(StructField(_, StringType, true)))
```

Then you can read the first file to dataframe as

```
val fileAdf = sqlContext.read.format("path to fileA")

//+-----+------+------+------+
//|col1 |col2  |start |end   |
//+-----+------+------+------+
//|dataa| data1| 9:10 | 9:15 |
//|datab| data2| 10:00| 10:10|
//|datac| data3| 11:20| 11:30|
//|datad| data4| 12:30| 12:40|
//+-----+------+------+------+
```

Similarly you can read second file (fileB)

```
val fileBdf = sqlContext.read.format("path to fileB")
//+------+-------+------+------+
//|col1  |col2   |start |end   |
//+------+-------+------+------+
//|dataaa| data11| 9:13 | 9:17 |
//|databb| data22| 10:02| 10:08|
//|datacc| data33| 6:20 | 6:30 |
//|datadd| data44| 12:31| 12:35|
//+------+-------+------+------+
```

Just use the same logic you explianed in the question in *spark-sql* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
fileBdf.as("fileB").join(fileAdf.as("fileA"), col("fileB.start") > col("fileA.start") && col("fileB.end") < col("fileA.end"))
  .select(col("fileB.col1"), col("fileB.col2"), col("fileB.start"), col("fileB.end"))
```

which should give you

```
+------+-------+------+------+
|col1  |col2   |start |end   |
+------+-------+------+------+
|databb| data22| 10:02| 10:08|
|datadd| data44| 12:31| 12:35|
+------+-------+------+------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: thanks for reply. looks like, this is basically a cartesian join. will this scale with huge datasets.?? any other alternative on the lines of udf or caching some data for the join to run faster.

Comment: You cannot call it a cartesian join. its a inner join and join only happens when the condition matches. i.e. inner join with where condition.

Comment: If one of the dataset is small then you can benefit from using broadcast. Thats all I can suggest. Good luck :) By the way what do you mean by `any other alternative on the lines of udf`?

Comment: Appreciate your effort, Though the prob. is both the files are really huge in few hundreds of GB. all this logic may not scale with such large datasets. this is why I was looking for some alternatives, may be a udf. but if udf is also not helpful, in that case, do we still have any alternative.?

Comment: did you try my answer or you are just assuming that its going to be slow. I am not aware of other alternative that would work faster.